# How to make questions using whose?

Tags: questions

1) Whose are these cattle?

2) Whose cattle are these?

Which structure is correct? If both, then what is the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Either is technically correct, but the second is by far the more common structure and would be the less likely to cause confusion.
There is no difference between the meaning of the two questions.